# How to setup p6spy driver in Arquillian tests on jBoss 7.x?

Tags: java, integration-testing, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian, p6spy

Apart from setting up the module in

```
JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/p6spy/main
```

adding `p6spy.jar` and `module.xml` saying:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.p6spy">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="p6spy.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

editing `standalone-full.xml` and adding an entry under `datasources/drivers`:

```
<driver name="p6spy" module="com.p6spy">
  <xa-datasource-class>com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

adding module dependency in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

```
<module name="com.p6spy"/>
```

replacing the original driver in data source definition with `p6spy` I'm still getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception:
  {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => 
    ["jboss.data-source.jboss/datasources/MyDsjboss.jdbc-driver.p6spyMissing
      [jboss.data-source.jboss/datasources/MyDsjboss.jdbc-driver.p6spy]"
    ]}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a rather old question, but I answer for the sake of future readers.

You don't need p6spy, JBoss AS 7 provides spying capabilities out of the box. Two steps are required.

- Put the following in logging section of your standalone.xml:

  ```
  <logger category="jboss.jdbc.spy">
      <level name="DEBUG"/>
  </logger>
  ```
- Add **spy=”true”** attribute in your DataSource configuration as follows:

  ```
  <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/testDS"
      pool-name="test" enabled="true"
      use-java-context="true" spy="true">
      <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</connection-url>
      <driver>postgresql</driver>
      <security>
          <user-name>postgres</user-name>
          <password>******</password>
      </security>
  </datasource>
  ```

That is it. You now have all database communication logged in your **server.log**. Spy log is actually a bit too verbose for my liking, but you do have all the information.

Comment: Works since JBoss 6.1
https://developer.jboss.org/message/880396#880396

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, p6spy does not seem to support XA datasources [(1)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/forums/forum/162085/topic/3062868) [(2)](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy/issues/2), which the above JBoss 7.x configuration requires.

Comment: since version 2.0.0 it has support for XA Datasources

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things,

first, you need to find all the dependencies p6spy uses, what I could see from pom is, it uses gnu-regexp and regexp are used. JBoss doesn't add them automatically, There could be more. Add these in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml and manifest.

Second, the spy.properties file needs to be added to the resources.

Sometime back I tried to hookup JMSBridge from HornetQ with SAR module. But this was just an MBean, now you have dependency jars, and a properties file.

[SAR Module](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1081)

Hope this helps and good luck

Answer (score 1):

First of all , you will need spy.properties file in you JBOSS classpath.
Since the default JBoss classpath points to tools.jar and run.jar, you may need to update your jboss classpath. ex:

```
set JBOSS_CLASSPATH=E:\jboss-1.1.1\server\directoryX
```

Assuming that spy.properties in this directoryX

P6Spy will be activated for your connection pool if you define it as the way you define other jdbc drivers. For example , Inside your datasrouce definition:

```
    <jndi-name>"your jndi name"</jndi-name>
<connection-url>"conn url"</connection-url>
**<driver-class>com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver</driver-class>**

    <user-name>"uid"</user-name>
    <password>"pswd"</password>
    <!-- pool sizes-->
```

Good Luck.

Comment: I've configured it already as suggested and it doesn't work. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you check if your <Drive>:/JBOSS**/server/<>/lib has p6spy.jar ? Something could have gone while your script copied the jar here.

Comment: i have defined a module in `/modules/com/p6spy/main` and put the jar there

Comment: Open launch configuration and under classpath, add the folder which has spy.properties file itself (in userentries). It works for me. I am using Jboss 6 though.

Comment: Yes, I have added `spy.properties` to the classpath. It's in the war produced by shrinkwrap.